# How should I generate requirements.txt? Pip Freeze not a good way

Tags: python-3.x, pip

How should I generate requirements.txt for Python projects?

Here is the problem I am having with pip freeze. Suppose my package P requires A, B, C. Suppose C is a library that imports X, Y, Z, but only X is needed by P. Then if I:

```
1) Install A
2) Install B
3) Install C, which installs X, Y, Z
4) Do a pip freeze into P's requirements.txt
```

Then P's requirements.txt will look like:

```
1) A
2) B
3) C
4) X
5) Y
6) Z
```

But Y and Z are not actually required in my Python installation for P to run.

Many of the answers assume that, Y must be. However, python is a dynamic language. It is very often the case that, for example C is a huge library that uses `numpy` or `pandas` for *some* functionality; but P doesn't call that part of the library - in this case, I don't *really* need to pull those in if I know what parts of C that P needs. If all libraries were "small"; this would be rare, however there are a lot of "kitchen sink" libraries.

As far as I can tell, running `pip freeze` to generate P's requirements will show you all dependencies of dependencies, and thus is a superset of P's actual dependencies.

Comment: I don't see this as a problem. 

If the requirements specifies the dependency's dependencies, does it do any harm? You'll end up with X, Y, Z installed when C gets installed even if you manually go and and remove X, Y, Z from the requirements.txt file. pip freeze makes the installation dependency is transparent to the user. Just take care to install everything related to your project in a virtual environment before running pip freeze.

Comment: I guess by "problem" I meant that I wanted the minimal set of requirements for P to run as P's requirements.txt. But due to the problem above the requirements balloons to a much larger set than what is needed for P to run.

Comment: You need C for P to run.  You need Y and Z for C to run.  By transitivity, you need Y and Z for P to run.  The whole point of requirements.txt is that your packages only change when you change them yourself.  If we didn't record Y and Z's versions, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: That is false. C is a library with lots of functionality. Some parts of that are dependent on Y and Z. However, not the parts called by P, so P can still import C, and if X is installed only, run. Remember that lots of Python errors are only encountered at runtime, so if P only calls the part of C importing X, everything is fine. I've edited my question to make this slightly more clear.

Comment: Python is a highly dynamic language.  Suppose a newer version of Y comes out, which monkey-patches X all over the place at import time.  You *don't* want that in your virtualenv, right?  Well, if you don't pin the Y version in requirements.txt, you could end up with it.

Comment: Well that is a different argument for why I might want Y (possibly post that as an answer below) than the transitive argument.

Comment: I've answered a suggestion in this another similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666949/1512555 I'm not sure how to link here so it'll be more visible (I just added it as a separate answer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose of a virtualenv is to have *total control* over the packages installed.

Suppose you only listed A, B, C, and X.  Every time you create a new virtualenv from that requirements file, you'll get the latest versions of Y and Z.  There are several problems with this:

1. **You can't know you're not using Y**: For a sufficiently complex project, it is nearly impossible to audit every codepath to ensure C never calls into Y.  You're not just worrying about your own code any more; you're worrying about C's code as well.  This just doesn't scale.
2. **Even if you're just importing Y, you're using it**: Python allows arbitrary code execution at import time.  A new version of Y could do all sorts of obnoxious things at import time, such as printing to stdout, monkey patching X, or just about anything else you can imagine.  A well-designed Y *shouldn't* do these things, but you'll find the quality of packages on PyPI highly variable.
3. **New versions of Y can pull in new dependencies**: If you include a new version of Y, you could end up adding package W to your virtualenv too, because the new version of Y requires it.  As more packages are added, the first two problems are exacerbated.  Worse, you might find that the new version of Y depends on a newer version of *X*, in which case you won't end up with the packages you actually want.
4. **Producing a known-good configuration is more important**: `pip freeze` is not designed to figure out minimal requirements.  It is designed to enable deploying a complete application to many different environments consistently.  That means it will err on the side of caution and list *everything* which could reasonably affect your project.

For these reasons, you should not try to remove Y and Z from your requirements file.

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is super helpful and a great answer to learn from!

Answer (score 6):

There is a python module called [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) . It generates requirements.txt based on imports in the project.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install the `pipreqs` library (e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge pipreqs`)
2. Change dir to the project folder (`cd your/repository`)
3. Run the command `pipreqs --force`

Or just `pipreqs --force your/repository`.

See additional information in the official source:
https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this question in a different stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666949/1512555 where I recommended using `pip-compile` from [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools)