# Is there a way to automatically get all necessary requirements in python code

Tags: python, anaconda

Is there a way to automatically get all necessary requirements in python code? I want to write a requirements.txt but what **conda env** gives are too many.

Comment: Please define "too many"!

Comment: @KlausD. During the development of the project, I would install some packages in my current **conda env**. Later i found they were totally useless, but **conda env export > environment.yml** donot know that. Therefore, I need to manually select the ones I really need or i write the env file myself.

Comment: Please check this question. It would help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363976/how-should-i-generate-requirements-txt-pip-freeze-not-a-good-way