# Is there a way to get directory package dependencies in python?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I am aware that `pip freeze > requirements.txt` exists, yet that that prints out my system packages, of which only a few my directory/ project needs.

I am not using a `virtualenv` so I'm pretty sure I can't print out local packages like that.

I also know that `pipdeptree` exsists but I also don't see how that solves my problem?

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` generates a single list of the specific packages used by your current Python interpreter (which can be a venv + base interpreter) on which pip is installed. While if you use `setup.py` the `install-requires` can list the minimum requirements. Basically your question is how to generate requirements minimum dependencies of the project and not from the current interpreter/venv. I don't know if that is possible using pip. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947988) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe tools like the following could help:

- [*pipreqs*](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/)
- [*pigar*](https://pypi.org/project/pigar/)

As far as I can tell, these tools read the code in the directory and try to figure out the dependencies required based on the *import* statements they found in the code.

***Related***:

- [Dependencies auto discovery for Python setuptools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61130177)
- [pip's requirements.txt best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61536466)
- [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31684375)
- [How to get the list of dependencies to be added to install_requires section in setup.py from a python lib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75586176)