# How to get the list of dependencies to be added to install_requires section in setup.py from a python lib

Tags: python, pip, python-import, python-packaging

I would like to know if there is any automatic way to discover the list of dependencies that I need to add to the `install_requires` section of a `setup.py` file for a Python library, without inspecting the code "*manually*".

It would be good if this tool is compatible with *pre-commit* as well, so that I get notified if dependencies change in a later commit.

Comment: seeking tool recommendations is off topic because it tends to be spammy.  the problem is also not simple _even with the code_.  it's pretty straightforward to discover 3rd party imports (such as with [classify-imports](https://github.com/asottile/classify-imports) -- one of my projects) -- but the pypi name doesn't have to match the module name (and often doesn't) and that mapping is difficult.  with the dependencies installed it's fairly straightforward to inspect the `RECORD` files against the module names, but that requires everything to already be installed!

Comment: Question has aready been asked many times: use pipreqs or pigar.

Comment: It answers. I did not found this question when searching for the solution. The only is that there is no integration to pre-commit.